# JTables with Buttons to delete things

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecelleditor

i have several Tables which display things like products which are saved in a database. So to get this products displayed i get a list from the database and give the list to the tablemodel.

Now i want a delete button in every row with which i can delete the product from the database.

Are there some good ways to do this? Right now i have implemented something that feels wrong. I have custom button which saves its row when its initialized and that makes a callback from the table (custom class extending jtable) to the view which then calls the controller to delete the entry from DB.

Comment: I'd, personally, use key bindings and attach a delete action directly to the table. I would also provide something like a delete button on the toolbar, using the same action, this way you reduce code replication. This also means you know have mutiple row selection capabilities (ie the user can click multiple, no sequential rows, and delete them in a single action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) by @camickr.